# Unable to Install SQL Server 2008 on Win Server 2008 R2 Datacenter

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying for the past three days to install SQL Server 2008 with SharePoint integrated mode in VMware Player, however I keep getting the following error:

`Reporting Services in SharePoint integrated mode is not supported for WORKGROUP edition`

I setup ADDS and have my computer part of that domain (therefore not a WORKGROUP). I am currently at my wits end and any help would be appreciated.

Current Roles installed: Application Server, Active Directory Domain Services, Web Server (IIS)

Features: Desktop Experience, Group Policy Management, Ink and Handwriting Services, Remote Server Administration Tools, Windows Process Activation Service, .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features

Comment: I don't understand, you've been at this for three days but didn't think to call MS even though you've given them a lot of money for these licences??

Comment: I'm only an intern setting up a SharePoint Dev environment. Thanks to DanBig's answer plus some of my co-worker's knowledge, we figured out a way to get around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, it is talking about Workgroup edition of SQL, not whether you are connected to a domain or workgroup. Sounds like you need to upgrade your version of SQL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283190.aspx

That article tells you what the problem is:

> Edition requirements for Reporting Services in SharePoint integrated mode include Developer, Evaluation, Standard, or Enterprise editions. There is no support for this feature in the Workgroup edition or in SQL Server Express with Advanced Services.

Comment: Thanks so much. You have no idea how frustrated I was starting to get.